# String Split in SSRS Report

Tags: c#-4.0, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have string "02Years02Months". In the SSRS Report i need to show the string like

"02 Years 02 Months". Is there any good method in SSRS report Expression.

Please advice, Thanks

Comment: how are you generating the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, Here is the answer

```
=Left(Fields!Value, 2) & " " & Mid(Fields!Value, 3, 5) & " " & Mid(Fields!Value, 8, 2) & " " & Right(Fields!Value,  6)
```

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 3):

=Left(Fields!String.Value, 2) & " " & Mid(Fields!String.Value, 3, 7) & " " & Right(Fields!String.Value, 6)

That's assuming your numbers will always be padding with zeroes as in the example above, and given you replace the Fields!String.Value with the field containing the string being returned in your report.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and the given expression is not splitting the string a my requirement.I think we Could write only one MID function in expression. are u able to generate the string to "02 Years 02 Months" ? –

Comment: Please write your proposed code using only 1 mid.  I don't think it can be done that way but we can take a look.  What is wrong with the code above?  Why is it not splitting it correctly for you?

Comment: For me Its splitting like '02 Years02 Months'